# Register a Moq mock object as type for a Unity container

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-container, moq

Since my sut class has a constructor with a `IUnityContainer` as parameter I like to setup a new Unity container im my unit test and pass it to the sut.
I like to use Moq here because I also have to veryfy for certain method calls. 
What I've tried here is

```
public interface IFoo
    {
        void Bar();
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();

            fooMock.Setup(x => x.Bar()).Callback(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello"));

            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType(typeof (IFoo), fooMock.Object.GetType());

            var sut = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
            sut.Bar();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

But this results in an `ResulutionFailedException`.
Any ideas what I can do or what might be an alternative to this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You already have an instance of object IFoo `fooMock`, so you need to register using [RegisterInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660894(v=pandp.20).aspx) method:

```
container.RegisterInstance<IFoo>(fooMock.Object);
```